# List Recent Comments from Across a Multi-site Network

Tags: comments, multisite

I'm look for a custom SQL query that will let me pull in the latest comments from across a WP multi-site install.

The end result will be identical to a regular recent comments widget, but from all sites within the installation.

Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: the problem is that you don't need just a SQL query to get the comments, but you also need to build the links to the comment author/blog post. And for that you probably need to make other queries... A easy but very slow way to do this is to use `switch_to_blog(x)`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I did some research based on [בניית אתרים](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/2487/)'s solution here, as I'm interested in this too.

First you need to get a list of blog IDs, and `get_blog_list()` is deprecated because it seems to be a "[suicidal database query](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/suicidal-multisite-database-queries)" :) Anyway looks like there will be a alternative in WP 3.2 called [wp_get_sites()](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14511). So use [this](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/14511/wp-get-sites.php) function instead. I suggest you pass the `'sort_column => 'last_updated'` argument, and `'limit'` the results to 20 or something like that. This would make the next query much faster.

So:

```
global $wpdb;
$number = 20; // maximum number of comments to display
$selects = array();
foreach (wp_get_sites() as $blog)
   // select only the fields you need here!
   $selects[] = "(SELECT comment_post_ID, comment_author, comment_author_email, comment_date_gmt, comment_content, post_title, {$blog['blog_id']} as blog_id FROM {$wpdb->base_prefix}{$blog['blog_id']}_comments
      LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->base_prefix}{$blog['blog_id']}_posts
      ON comment_post_id = id
      WHERE post_status = 'publish'
        AND post_password = ''
        AND comment_approved = '1'
        AND comment_type = ''
       ORDER BY comment_date_gmt DESC LIMIT {$number})"; // real number is (number * # of blogs)

  $comments = $wpdb->get_results(implode(" UNION ALL ", $selects)." ORDER BY comment_date_gmt DESC", OBJECT);
```

Then render the output:

```
<ul>
<?php
$count = 0;
foreach((array)$comments as $comment):
  $count++;
  if($count == $number+1) break; 
  ?>
  <li>
   <?php echo get_avatar($comment->comment_author_email, 32); ?>
   <a href="<?php echo get_blog_permalink($comment->blog_id, $comment->comment_post_ID); ?>" title="commented on <?php echo strip_tags($comment->post_title); ?>">
   <?php echo $comment->comment_author; ?> wrote: 
   <?php echo convert_smilies(wp_trim_excerpt($comment->comment_content)); ?>
   (<?php echo human_time_diff(strtotime("{$comment->comment_date_gmt}")); ?>)  
   </a>
  </li>
<?php
endforeach;
?>
</ul>
```

You should also cache the results, and flush the cache like once every 10 minutes or so.

Comment: Excellent! Worked almost perfect the first time. The only thing I had to do was to pass an empty $args to wp_get_sites(), otherwise WP freaked out about missing arguments.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$sqlstr = '';
$blog_list = get_blog_list( 0, 'all' );
$sqlstr = "SELECT 1 as blog_id, comment_date, comment_id, comment_post_id, comment_content, comment_date_gmt, comment_author, comment_author_email from ".$table_prefix ."comments where comment_approved = 1 ";
$uni = '';
foreach ($blog_list AS $blog) {
    $uni = ' union ';
    $sqlstr .= $uni . " SELECT ".$blog['blog_id']." as blog_id, comment_date, comment_id, comment_post_id, comment_content, comment_date_gmt, comment_author, comment_author_email   from ".$table_prefix .$blog['blog_id']."_comments where comment_approved = 1 ";                
}
$limit = ''; //set your limit
$limit = ' LIMIT 0, '. (int)$wgt_count;
$sqlstr .= " ORDER BY comment_date_gmt desc " . $limit; 
$comm_list = $wpdb->get_results($sqlstr, ARRAY_A);
```

and you might want to have a look at [diamond multisite widgets plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/diamond-multisite-widgets/)
witch already implements this a a widget and as a shortcode.

hopes this helps.

Comment: get_blog_list() is considered a suicidal function.