# Using $wpdb Class to Pull Recent Comments Across a Network

Tags: multisite, mysql, wpdb

Been looking for a clean and simple way to produce comments from across a network using the $wpdb database class.

I did find [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7014/list-recent-comments-from-across-a-multi-site-network), which has been protected, and is four years old.

I wrapped it in a function and attempted to call it on the front page of my network, but it didn't work.  I also played with the mysql statement, but could not get it to produce any output.

Here's what I have:

```
function display_sitewide_comments() {

global $wpdb;
$number = 20; // maximum number of comments to display
$selects = array();
$args = array();
foreach (wp_get_sites( $args ) as $blog)
   // select only the fields you need here!
   $selects[] = "(SELECT comment_post_ID, comment_author, comment_author_email, comment_date_gmt, comment_content, post_title, {$blog['blog_id']} as blog_id FROM {$wpdb->base_prefix}{$blog['blog_id']}_comments
      LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->base_prefix}{$blog['blog_id']}_posts
      ON comment_post_id = id
      WHERE post_status = 'publish'
        AND post_password = ''
        AND comment_approved = '1'
        AND comment_type = ''
       ORDER BY comment_date_gmt DESC LIMIT {$number})"; // real number is (number * # of blogs)

  $comments = $wpdb->get_results(implode(" UNION ALL ", $selects)." ORDER BY comment_date_gmt DESC", OBJECT);

$count = 0;
foreach((array)$comments as $comment):
  $count++;
  if($count == $number+1) break; 
  ?>
  <li>
   <?php echo get_avatar($comment->comment_author_email, 32); ?>
   <a href="<?php echo get_blog_permalink($comment->blog_id, $comment->comment_post_ID); ?>" title="commented on <?php echo strip_tags($comment->post_title); ?>">
   <?php echo $comment->comment_author; ?> wrote: 
   <?php echo convert_smilies(wp_trim_excerpt($comment->comment_content)); ?>
   (<?php echo human_time_diff(strtotime("{$comment->comment_date_gmt}")); ?>)  
   </a>
  </li>
<?php
endforeach;
}
```

I'm wondering, since the post is 4 years old, if something has changed in core, or the database structure to make the query obsolete? Or possibly there is an error that I cannot see. In debug mode it does not throw any errors.  I also declared and used an empty $args array as was suggested in the original post.

Thought this was a very useful function and that more people than me were having trouble with it.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really have a closing `?>` before the closing `}` (second last and last line)?

Comment: No I do not, thank you for catching that. I've made the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use [`get_comments()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments), instead of trying to roll your own with `$wpdb`?

```
function display_sitewide_comments() {
    $sites = wp_get_sites();
    $network_comments = array();
    $max = 20;
    foreach( $sites as $site ) {
        switch_to_blog( $site->blog_id );    
        $args = array(
        'number' => $max,
            'status' => 'approved',
    );
        $network_comments[$site->blog_id] = get_comments( $args );
        restore_current_blog();
    }
    // inspect the comments
    var_dump( $network_comments );
}
```

**Edited to add:**

If you just want the 20 most recent comments, you could change `$network_comments[$site->blog_id] = get_comments( $args );` to something like

```
$comments = get_comments( $args );
foreach( $comments as $comments ) {
    $network_comments[] = $comment;
}
```

Then, at the end of the loop, use [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort) to sort the comments based on `$comment->comment_date_gmt` and then truncate it to `$max` values.

### References

- [`wp_get_sites()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_sites)
- [`switch_to_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog) & [`restore_current_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/restore_current_blog)
- [`get_comments()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments)

Comment: What about speed of this code? Isn't it very slow? AFAIR `switch_to_blog` is rather time-consuming...

Comment: I was going to ask the same thing. But what if I use the Transients API to cache it? And, if my network runs in the low hundreds, is it still an issue?

Comment: Fair enough, `switch_to_blog()` might slow things down. Using the Transients API to cache would definitely speed things up. OTOH, you could use transients or the Options API when the comment is approved -- hook to [`comment_unapproved_to_approved`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/comment_%28old_status%29_to_%28new_status%29) that does an [`update_site_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_site_option), for instance.

Comment: It's a step in the right direction. Would be nice if there was a function for this in core. Much like wp_get_sites().